# Convert "wstring" to "const UInt8 *"

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, unicode, wstring

I had to convert wstring to (UInt8 *). 
Also, I had this string:

```
    wstring str;
```

Could you help me to convert, please?
I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
    wstring str;
    uint8 *buf = reinterpret_cast<uint8>(str);
    CFStringRef CFStringCreateWithBytes (CFAllocatorRef alloc,
                                         const UInt8 *buf,
                                         CFIndex sizeOfBuf,
                                         CFStringEncoding encoding,
                                         Boolean isExternalRepresentation);
```

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that? An `std::wstring` consists of `wchar_t`s   which should be larger than `uint8`s, and most likely they contain strings in different encodings.

Comment: @Biffen, I want it, because I want to pass parameter "str" to the function, which requires UInt32 * buf... 
CFStringRef CFStringCreateWithBytes (
   CFAllocatorRef alloc,
   const UInt8 *bytes,
   CFIndex numBytes,
   CFStringEncoding encoding,
   Boolean isExternalRepresentation
);

Comment: `UInt32` or `UInt8`?! Which encoding is this function expecting? Is that the same encoding as your `std::wstring str`? If they are the same you could use a pointer to `str`'s data (hint: `str.c_str()`), otherwise you would have to convert it first, which is not particularly trivial.

Comment: Of course, UInt8.... Sorry....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wchar_t` is 32bit on OSX, thus `std::wstring` can hold a UTF-32 encoded string:

```
std::wstring str = ...;
CFStringRef encoded = CFStringCreateWithBytes(
                                     kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                     reinterpret_cast<uint8*>(str.c_str()),
                                     str.size() * sizeof(wchar_t),
                                     kCFStringEncodingUTF32LE,
                                     false);
```